# Use a transformation to convert word to a key/value pair of (word, 1) in RDD in python

Tags: python, bigdata, rdd

The data is like
`[['my', 'name', 'is', 'lala'],['what', 'is', 'your','name']]`
and we want it as
`[('my',1),('name',1),...]`
using [python RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) and lambda functions

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [(w,1) for l in data for w in l]
# [('my', 1), ('name', 1), ('is', 1), ('lala', 1), ('what', 1), ('is', 1), ('your', 1), ('name', 1)]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the number reflect the index of the sublist?